# What is the minimum number of data points that could have been used to generate these percentages?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

An agency responsible for investigating and prosecuting residential tenancy offenses initiated 3 prosecutions during the 2016-17 financial period.

These are the percentages of 5 categories of **investigations** during that period:

1. 9.8% - Agreement terms breach
2. 14.6% - Unlawful entry
3. 19.3% - Failure to provide documentation
4. 24.2% - Non-lodgement of bond
5. 32.1% - Other

What is the minimum number of investigations that could have been used as data points to determine those percentages?

Comment: Are these percentages (a) absolutely accurate or (b) rounded to one decimal place?

Comment: According to what my chemistry teacher told me when I was 16, the answer is (b) and the values should be treated as +/-0.05%

Comment: By brute force, the min num of investigations is $471 = 46+69+91+114+151$. the next one is $492 = 48+82+95+119+158$.

Comment: Thanks, 471 seems good